# Can I group Airplay2 output devices into one group?

Tags: airplay, homepod

Can I group Airplay2 output devices into one group?

If I want to play a song on both Sonos sets (3 speakers) and Apple Homepod, I need to select first Sonos, and then Homepod from iOS.

Can I group all devices into one group, so that I can just select it once?